# Android LoaderManager Access Remote MSSQL Database Table

Tags: android, sql-server, cursor, loader

got a question in my Android development haunting me for days and could not solve it. Here below is the background info:

1. I am using LoaderManager in one of my Fragements, which is supposed to initialize a loader by accessing remote MSSQL database table (named as 'todolist') and return back a Cursor;
2. I had put the initialization code of the LoaderManager in the snippets public void onCreate() or public View onCreateView(). But both returning me an error with "java.lang.NullPointerException: Attempt to invoke interface method 'int android.database.Cursor.getCount()' on a null object reference at *****.****.****.****.*******.com.****.data.AllToDoListFragment.onLoadFinished(AllToDoListFragment.java:208)";
3. Obviously, the Cursor data in my code has not been initialized;
4. So my question goes down to either:

   4.1. find a way in the onCreateLoader snippet to access my MSSQL database table so that it can successfully return me a cursor or:

   4.2. somebody show me how to do it in asyncTask.

BTW, I know how to use AsyncTask to retrieve my data from my remote MSSQL database table and it could be displayed in my RecycleView. But as I learn that Cursor is much better an option for the solution so I wonder how to do it.
Unfortunately, I could not find any useful hint related from the Internet.

Here below are the codes snippets of AllToDoListFragment.java

```
public class AllToDoListFragment extends Fragment implements
        LoaderManager.LoaderCallbacks<Cursor>,
        NewToDoListAdapter.NewToDoListAdapterOnClickHandler{

/*
 * The columns of data that we are interested in displaying within our MainActivity's list of
 * weather data.
 */
public static final String[] MAIN_TODOLIST_PROJECTION = {
        ToDoListContract.ToDoListEntry._ID,
        ToDoListContract.ToDoListEntry.COLUMN_PROJECTNAME,
        ToDoListContract.ToDoListEntry.COLUMN_RAISEDDATE,
        ToDoListContract.ToDoListEntry.COLUMN_DEADLINE,
        ToDoListContract.ToDoListEntry.COLUMN_RESP1NAME,
        ToDoListContract.ToDoListEntry.COLUMN_ISSUE,
};

/*
 * We store the indices of the values in the array of Strings above to more quickly be able to
 * access the data from our query. If the order of the Strings above changes, these indices
 * must be adjusted to match the order of the Strings.
 */
public static final int INDEX_TODOLIST_ID = 0;
public static final int INDEX_TODOLIST_PROJECTNAME = 1;
public static final int INDEX_TODOLIST_RAISEDDATE = 2;
public static final int INDEX_TODOLIST_DEADLINE = 3;
public static final int INDEX_TODOLIST_RESP1NAME = 4;
public static final int INDEX_TODOLIST_ISSUE = 5;


/*
 * This ID will be used to identify the Loader responsible for loading our ToDoList. In
 * some cases, one Activity can deal with many Loaders. However, in our case, there is only one.
 * We will still use this ID to initialize the loader and create the loader for best practice.
 * Please note that 45 was chosen arbitrarily. You can use whatever number you like, so long as
 * it is unique and consistent.
 */
private static final int ID_TODOLIST_LOADER = 144;

private NewToDoListAdapter mNewToDoListAdapter;
private RecyclerView mRecyclerView;
private int mPosition = RecyclerView.NO_POSITION;

private ProgressBar mLoadingIndicator;

public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    /*
     * Ensures a loader is initialized and active. If the loader doesn't already exist, one is
     * created and (if the activity/fragment is currently started) starts the loader. Otherwise
     * the last created loader is re-used.
     */
    // TODO 4: got to check if the following Loader is working or not
    getLoaderManager().initLoader(ID_TODOLIST_LOADER, null, this);

    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
}

@Override
public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
                         Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    final View rootView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_all_to_do_list, container, false);

    /*
     * Using findViewById, we get a reference to our RecyclerView from xml. This allows us to
     * do things like set the adapter of the RecyclerView and toggle the visibility.
     */
    mRecyclerView = (RecyclerView) rootView.findViewById(R.id.recyclerview_newtdl);

    /*
     * The ProgressBar that will indicate to the user that we are loading data. It will be
     * hidden when no data is loading.
     *
     * Please note: This so called "ProgressBar" isn't a bar by default. It is more of a
     * circle. We didn't make the rules (or the names of Views), we just follow them.
     */
    mLoadingIndicator = (ProgressBar) rootView.findViewById(R.id.pb_loading_indicator_newtdl);

    /*
     * A LinearLayoutManager is responsible for measuring and positioning item views within a
     * RecyclerView into a linear list. This means that it can produce either a horizontal or
     * vertical list depending on which parameter you pass in to the LinearLayoutManager
     * constructor. In our case, we want a vertical list, so we pass in the constant from the
     * LinearLayoutManager class for vertical lists, LinearLayoutManager.VERTICAL.
     *
     * There are other LayoutManagers available to display your data in uniform grids,
     * staggered grids, and more! See the developer documentation for more details.
     *
     * The third parameter (shouldReverseLayout) should be true if you want to reverse your
     * layout. Generally, this is only true with horizontal lists that need to support a
     * right-to-left layout.
     */
    LinearLayoutManager layoutManager =
            new LinearLayoutManager(getActivity(), LinearLayoutManager.VERTICAL, false);

    /* setLayoutManager associates the LayoutManager we created above with our RecyclerView */
    mRecyclerView.setLayoutManager(layoutManager);

    /*
     * Use this setting to improve performance if you know that changes in content do not
     * change the child layout size in the RecyclerView
     */
    mRecyclerView.setHasFixedSize(true);

    /*
     * The NewToDoListAdapter is responsible for linking our weather data with the Views that
     * will end up displaying our weather data.
     *
     * Although passing in "this" twice may seem strange, it is actually a sign of separation
     * of concerns, which is best programming practice. The ForecastAdapter requires an
     * Android Context (which all Activities are) as well as an onClickHandler. Since our
     * MainActivity implements the ForecastAdapter ForecastOnClickHandler interface, "this"
     * is also an instance of that type of handler.
     */
    // TODO 3: got to check if the paras below are valid or not
    mNewToDoListAdapter = new NewToDoListAdapter(getContext(), this);

    /* Setting the adapter attaches it to the RecyclerView in our layout. */
    mRecyclerView.setAdapter(mNewToDoListAdapter);


    showLoading();


    // TODO 5: SyncUtils might not be needed here
    //          becuase asynctask is used
    //SunshineSyncUtils.initialize(this);

    return rootView;
}

/**
 * Called by the {@link android.support.v4.app.LoaderManagerImpl} when a new Loader needs to be
 * created. This Fragment only uses one loader, so we don't necessarily NEED to check the
 * loaderId, but this is certainly best practice.
 *
 * @param loaderId The loader ID for which we need to create a loader
 * @param bundle   Any arguments supplied by the caller
 * @return A new Loader instance that is ready to start loading.
 */
@Override
public Loader<Cursor> onCreateLoader(int loaderId, Bundle bundle) {
    switch (loaderId) {
        case ID_TODOLIST_LOADER:
            /* URI for all rows of ToDoList data in our todolist table */
            Uri todolistQueryUri = ToDoListContract.ToDoListEntry.CONTENT_URI;
            /* Sort order: Ascending by date */
            String sortOrder = ToDoListContract.ToDoListEntry.COLUMN_DEADLINE + " ASC";
            /*
             * A SELECTION in SQL declares which rows you'd like to return. In our case, we
             * want all todolist data that is stored in our todolist table.
             * We created a handy method to do that in our WeatherEntry class.
             */
            String selection = ToDoListContract.ToDoListEntry.getSqlSelectDeadlineFromLastMonth();

            return new CursorLoader(getActivity(),
                    todolistQueryUri,
                    MAIN_TODOLIST_PROJECTION,
                    selection,
                    null,
                    sortOrder);

        default:
            throw new RuntimeException("Loader Not Implemented: " + loaderId);
    }
}

/**
 * Called when a Loader has finished loading its data.
 *
 * NOTE: There is one small bug in this code. If no data is present in the cursor do to an
 * initial load being performed with no access to internet, the loading indicator will show
 * indefinitely, until data is present from the ContentProvider. This will be fixed in a
 * future version of the course.
 *
 * @param loader The Loader that has finished.
 * @param data   The data generated by the Loader.
 */
@Override
public void onLoadFinished(Loader<Cursor> loader, Cursor data) {
    mNewToDoListAdapter.swapCursor(data);
    if (mPosition == RecyclerView.NO_POSITION) mPosition = 0;
    mRecyclerView.smoothScrollToPosition(mPosition);
    if (data.getCount() != 0) showNewToDoListDataView();
}

/**
 * Called when a previously created loader is being reset, and thus making its data unavailable.
 * The application should at this point remove any references it has to the Loader's data.
 *
 * @param loader The Loader that is being reset.
 */
@Override
public void onLoaderReset(Loader<Cursor> loader) {
    /*
     * Since this Loader's data is now invalid, we need to clear the Adapter that is
     * displaying the data.
     */
    mNewToDoListAdapter.swapCursor(null);
}

/**
 * This method is for responding to clicks from our list.
 *
 * @param id unique id number for the todolist item.
 * @see ToDoListContract.ToDoListEntry#_ID
 */
@Override
public void onClick(long id) {
    Intent tdlDetailIntent = new Intent(getActivity(), TDLDetailActivity.class);
    Uri uriForIDClicked = ToDoListContract.ToDoListEntry.buildToDoListUriWithID(id);
    tdlDetailIntent.setData(uriForIDClicked);
    startActivity(tdlDetailIntent);
}

/**
 * This method will make the View for the weather data visible and hide the error message and
 * loading indicator.
 * <p>
 * Since it is okay to redundantly set the visibility of a View, we don't need to check whether
 * each view is currently visible or invisible.
 */
private void showNewToDoListDataView() {
    /* First, hide the loading indicator */
    mLoadingIndicator.setVisibility(View.INVISIBLE);
    /* Finally, make sure the weather data is visible */
    mRecyclerView.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
}

/**
 * This method will make the loading indicator visible and hide the todolist View and error
 * message.
 * <p>
 * Since it is okay to redundantly set the visibility of a View, we don't need to check whether
 * each view is currently visible or invisible.
 */
private void showLoading() {
    /* Then, hide the weather data */
    mRecyclerView.setVisibility(View.INVISIBLE);
    /* Finally, show the loading indicator */
    mLoadingIndicator.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
}
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I you may try  like bellow...I have retrieved profile name from contact..

```
public class AllToDoListFragment extends Fragment implements  android.support.v4.app.LoaderManager.LoaderCallbacks<Cursor> {
@Nullable
@Override
public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, @Nullable ViewGroup container, @Nullable Bundle savedInstanceState) {
   // return super.onCreateView(inflater, container, savedInstanceState);
    View rootView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_1, container, false);
    getLoaderManager().initLoader(0, null, this);

    return  rootView;
}


@Override
public android.support.v4.content.Loader<Cursor> onCreateLoader(int id, Bundle args) {
    return new android.support.v4.content.CursorLoader(getActivity(),
            // Retrieve data rows for the device user's 'profile' contact.
            Uri.withAppendedPath( ContactsContract.Profile.CONTENT_URI,ContactsContract.Contacts.Data.CONTENT_DIRECTORY),
            ProfileQuery.PROJECTION,

            //Don't select anything here null will return all available fields

            null,
            null,
            null);
}

@Override
public void onLoadFinished(android.support.v4.content.Loader<Cursor> loader, Cursor cursor) {
    ArrayList<String> DataArray = new ArrayList<String>();
    String name=null;
    String photoUrl=null;

    cursor.moveToFirst();
    while (!cursor.isAfterLast()) {
        //here where you get your data and its type
        String  TypeName=cursor.getString(ProfileQuery.EMAIL);//this will give you field name
        String  Data=cursor.getString(ProfileQuery.FAMILY_NAME);//this will give you field data

        String email = cursor.getString(ProfileQuery.EMAIL);;
        String familyName = cursor.getString(ProfileQuery.FAMILY_NAME);
        String url = cursor.getString(ProfileQuery.PHOTO);


        if (TypeName !=null){
            name = TypeName;

        }
        if(url !=null){
            photoUrl =url;
        }

        cursor.moveToNext();


    }

  Log.e("*****name",name);

}

@Override
public void onLoaderReset(android.support.v4.content.Loader<Cursor> loader) {

}


private interface ProfileQuery {
    String[] PROJECTION = {
            ContactsContract.CommonDataKinds.Email.ADDRESS,
            ContactsContract.CommonDataKinds.Email.IS_PRIMARY,
            ContactsContract.CommonDataKinds.StructuredName.FAMILY_NAME,
            ContactsContract.CommonDataKinds.StructuredName.GIVEN_NAME,
            ContactsContract.CommonDataKinds.Phone.NUMBER,
            ContactsContract.CommonDataKinds.Phone.IS_PRIMARY,
            ContactsContract.CommonDataKinds.Photo.PHOTO_URI,
            ContactsContract.Contacts.Data.MIMETYPE
    };

    // int ADDRESS = 0;
    //  int NUMBER = 1;

    /** Column index for the email address in the profile query results */
    int EMAIL = 0;
    /** Column index for the primary email address indicator in the profile query results */
    int IS_PRIMARY_EMAIL = 1;
    /** Column index for the family name in the profile query results */
    int FAMILY_NAME = 2;
    /** Column index for the given name in the profile query results */
    int GIVEN_NAME = 3;
    /** Column index for the phone number in the profile query results */
    int PHONE_NUMBER = 4;
    /** Column index for the primary phone number in the profile query results */
    int IS_PRIMARY_PHONE_NUMBER = 5;
    /** Column index for the photo in the profile query results */
    int PHOTO = 6;
    /** Column index for the MIME type in the profile query results */
    int MIME_TYPE = 7;
}
```

Comment: Haue, thanks for your comments. However, this is not what I want. I want to know how to return a cursor of querying the database table from a remote ms sql server. Any idea? Thanks again.

Answer (score 0):

For those who are concerned, there might be a wrong direction from where I posted the question. It might be good to use Webservice (like RESTFul) instead. Still digging into the details and will post more accurate solutions when it's ready.